# StringBuilder delete methods

Tags: java, methods, stringbuilder

`StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();`

`builder.append("hello");`

The length of `builder` is 5.
So, if I call `builder.deleteCharAt(5)` I rightfully get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`
yet I can call `builder.delete(0,5)` and this works successfully.
Can I know why?

Comment: What do their respective Javadoc entries say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is Java API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562767/what-is-java-api)

Comment: Your question is basically "Why does the `delete(int, int)` method of `StringBuilder` behave exactly the way it is described in its official documentation". Which isn't a very good question.

Comment: I'm just reading it now. It takes one from the end variable, why though?

Comment: I believe that is so that one can write `builder.delete(0, builder.length())`. It is a custom to make the ending indexes exclusive, although you as developer could choose to make it inclusive for your own methods if you want to.

Comment: This is the same behaviour as String.substring. It helps to read it as if you're trying to delete the string *between* the specified indexes, so 0|hello|5.

Comment: here's an example that might give you a hint: `builder.append("helloHello").delete(builder.indexOf("H")`.

it will delete only the first "hello" instead of "helloH". Which might be a more common usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is fine. The intent is different.

Lets try this for example:

```
String builder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("hello").append("hello");
sb.delete(0,5);
sb.toString();
```

It prints `"hello"`.

Had you read the documentation, you'd see that the end is non-inclusive, meaning it will delete from `start` to `end-1`, hence no IndexOutOfBounds.

However, try this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

builder.append("hello");
builder.delete(0,7);
```

and you will most likely get an index out of bounds.

EDIT:
Personal gripe - it's a fine balance between stopping someone from shooting themselves in the foot by throwing an exception, and just letting them do it but actually doing nothing in that case.

One example of "you really can't do this, and will get an exception" is e.g. calling init() twice on something important that should really be initialized only once.

One example of "You shouldn't do this, but I won't crash your program if you do" is e.g. calling init() twice on a logger.

In this particular case, trying to delete a character that is out of bounds, falls into the first category. So that "it's **your** bug, not mine" kinda thing.

But deleting a range - personally - shouldn't even throw an exception. If the range is bigger than the length of the string, it's my thing's job to delete everything (in the range you specified), and it's your bug to figure out why you deleted more than you did.

And this is exactly the kind of thing that demonstrates why writing documentation is important.

So that if you did this:

```
String builder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("hello").append("Jello");
sb.delete(0,6); //e.g. you somehow thought that hello is of length 6
sb.toString();
```

and get a `Jello` it's your thing to figure out why. Your bug. Not mine.
if you did `sb.delete(0,7);` and get a `ello`, it's your thing to figure out why. Your bug, not mine. The docs are clear on what will happen.

But it depends on what the "thing" is. If it's important, nope, you'll get an exception. If it's something stupid, sure, go ahead, shoot yourself in the foot, harmlessly.

However, in this particular case, i'd allow even this code to work fine:

```
String builder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("hello").append("hello");
sb.delete(0,200);
sb.toString();
```

and not throw an exception. But internally, i'd only do `delete(0,10)`

TL;DR - it's not inconsistent, it's working exactly like it says it works.

Comment: as a SDK / component developer, you actually need to think about how your thing is going to be used, and not just about how your thing works... and like i said, not all cases/intents of use deserve an exception. Sometimes you just silently do what you can do, and let the user think his code works perfectly. even with strange values  But it doesn't apply to every single method / usecase.